# Many to MAny Object model in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In a *Student* and *Group* relationship, where a student can create a 'group' of which other students can be members, this is a many to many relationship.

Now, i need to be keep track of which student is owner/creator of the group.

So, if i was not using Hibernate ORM i would have definately created the relationship as [image: Student group many to many rel]

I would like to know if there is a better way, to avoid creating the *mapping* table as object in hibernate orm?

Comment: If there is no such table, where would you store `isOwner`? At the moment that you add a property you need an object to access it.

Comment: @SJuan76 - thats exactly my question. is there a better way to represent this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mapping` table is definitely the way to go when developing a many-to-many relationship. If you don't want to store the `isOwner` in the `mapping` table, you could store an `ownerId` in the `Group` table and have that point to a particular `Student` id.

If you look at [this tutorial](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-1.html), they don't generate a hibernate object for the many-to-many relationship, but the table still exists. You're going to need a join table of some sort to correctly represent a many-to-many relationship. By moving the `isOwner` into the group, you won't need the hibernate object to access the owning student since you can get to it from the `Owner` object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get what you mean by moving the isowner into group. I am currently trying it out.